# How to get name of fingerprint Android device?

Tags: android, fingerprint, android-biometric-prompt

I work with biometric fingerprint Android. When we register a fingerprint at settings, we also store the name of a fingerprint. My question is, is it possible we get the name of the fingerprint? I have code just authentication fingerprint, but I need name of the fingerprint. Thank you for help.

```
biometricPrompt = new BiometricPrompt(activity, executor, new BiometricPrompt.AuthenticationCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthenticationError(int errorCode, @NonNull CharSequence errString) {
            super.onAuthenticationError(errorCode, errString);
            if (errorCode == BiometricPrompt.ERROR_NEGATIVE_BUTTON) {
                // user clicked negative button
                if (dialogMessage!=null && dialogMessage.isShowing()) {
                    // Dismiss dialog
                    dialogMessage.dismiss();
                    stopHandler();
                }
            } else {
                // Called when an unrecoverable error has been encountered and the operation is complete.
                displayToastMessage("text", "", R.string.unrecoverable_error_has_been_encountered);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onAuthenticationSucceeded(@NonNull BiometricPrompt.AuthenticationResult result) {
            super.onAuthenticationSucceeded(result);
            // Sent data to server
            showDialogBiometric();
        }

        @Override
        public void onAuthenticationFailed() {
            super.onAuthenticationFailed();
            // Called when a biometric is valid but not recognized.
            displayToastMessage("text", "", R.string.valid_biometric_not_recognized);
        }
    });

    promptInfo = new BiometricPrompt.PromptInfo.Builder()
            .setTitle(getString(R.string.attendance))
            .setDescription(getString(R.string.absent_with_fingerprint))
            .setNegativeButtonText(getString(R.string.cancel))
            .build();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When we register a fingerprint at settings, we also store the name of a fingerprint

Not necessarily.

> is it possible we get the name of the fingerprint?

No, sorry.